# Are there ETFs that mostly buy options?

Tags: options, etf

I am aware that there are ETFs that mostly sell options. For example, ETFs that track the Cboe S&P 500 BuyWrite Index (BXM) will consistently sell covered call options, and ETFs that track the Cboe S&P 500 PutWrite Index (PUT) will consistently sell T-bill-secured put options.

Now I am wondering if there are ETFs that mostly buy options (instead of selling options). Do such ETFs exist? If not, why don't they exist? (e.g. regulatory problems, risk of complete loss, etc.)

In particular, I am interested in ETFs that consistently buy options of a particular type (i.e. all puts, or all calls) on an underlying stock index.